# Expectation of Product of Normal Random Variable Exponential and Some Function?

Tags: probability

$$X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^{2})$$
$$X = \mu + \sigma Z$$

Show that:
$$\text{E}\bigg(\text{exp}(\theta X) \cdot f(X)\bigg) = \text{exp}(\theta \mu+ \frac{1}{2} \theta^{2}\sigma^{2}) \cdot \text{E}\bigg(f(X + \theta \sigma^{2})\bigg)$$

My approach is:

- Assume the two functions multiplied are independent, hence can conveniently decompose expectation.
  $$\color{blue}{\text{E}\bigg(\text{exp}(\theta X) \cdot f(X)\bigg) = \text{E}\bigg(\text{exp}(\theta X)\bigg) \cdot \text{E}\bigg(f(X)\bigg)}$$
- I basically have an expectation of lognormal random variable in the first factor; which is a standard result.
  $$\color{blue}{= \text{exp}(\theta \mu + \frac{1}{2} \theta\sigma^{2}) \cdot \text{E}\bigg(f(X)\bigg)}$$
- This does not look like the expected answer ☹.

Comment: please correct the missing parenthesis in your third line. Also, two functions of the same random variable can never be independent so you cannot decompose expectation like you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E} \left [ e^{\theta X} f(X) \right ] &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\theta t} e^{-\frac{(t - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} f(t) dt 
\end{align*}

then do a change of variable $t = y + \theta \sigma^2$ to get

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left [ e^{\theta X} f(X) \right ]  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\theta (y + \theta \sigma^2 )} e^{-\frac{(y + \theta \sigma^2 - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} f(y + \theta \sigma^2 ) dy 
\end{align*}

Simplifying this gets you

\begin{align*}
    e^{\theta \mu  + \frac{1}{2} \theta^2 \sigma^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2 }}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y + \theta \sigma^2) e^{- \frac{(y - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} dy  =  e^{\theta \mu  + \frac{1}{2} \theta^2 \sigma^2} \mathbb{E} [f(X + \theta \sigma^2)]
\end{align*}
which is the desired answer.

Comment: Seems you are assuming $\text{exp}(\theta X) f(X)$ is normal; is that correct? Also, why the peculiar choice for the form of variable $t$?

Comment: $(1)$ I am not assuming that - if $X$ is normal, it is $\textbf{not}$ true in general that $\exp(\theta X) f(X)$ is also normal. $(2)$ The variable of integration is a dummy variable; you can name it anything you want.

Comment: 1) In line one the PDF you are integrating has the normal form; I am guessing you are using LOTUS here 2) I meant what was the reasoning for choosing expression $y+\theta \sigma^{2}$?

Comment: Yes, I am using LOTUS. I chose $t = y + \theta \sigma^2$ to get the desired answer. There is no other reason.